# when i deployed to iis jq grid plugin grid is not loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, jqgrid

if i assign jqDataUrl to url of jqgrid grid is loaded with items in development server but in iis it is not loading ,i tried using @Url.Action as shown below but items are not loaded in development server or iis server what is the problem in url and iam using JQGrid in default.htm page?

```
var jqDataUrl = "jQGrid/LoadjqData";

 $("#jqTable").jqGrid({
            // Ajax related configurations
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadjqData", "jQGrid")',
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you don't need the quotes around the Url.Action, so:

```
var jqDataUrl = "jQGrid/LoadjqData";

$("#jqTable").jqGrid({
        // Ajax related configurations
        url: @Url.Action("LoadjqData", "jQGrid"),
```

is better (where "LoadjqData" is an action of the "jQGrid" controller).

Comment: no, it does **need** the quotes.. the OP says it works in development server and not in IIS..

Comment: It gives me error like conditional compilation turned off wj=hen i used without quotes

Comment: Hi  AthibaN , If i use var url: "jQGrid/LoadjqData",it works in development server and not in iis,but if i use url: '@Url.Action("LoadjqData", "jQGrid")',then It doesnt work in development server as well in iis